# Error in sharepoint workflow "Invalid WorkflowInstanceID parameter in URL."

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am currently trying to move a workflow from one site onto another. It has imported correctly but I am getting a strange error. The forms on my workflow are producing this error whenever I press the submit button. I have researched this a bit and all answers seem to point to an automated task called Workflow auto cleanup which removes any older workflows.

However this does not appear to be the problem for me as I am working with new tasks and also I have tried turning this off. One thing I did notice is that the WorkflowInstanceID is missing from the URL after clicking the button. Whereas in the initial site it came from the WorkflowInstanceID is included.

So if the initial URL were:

> https://Contoso.com/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List=3ae780d1-8117-4d17-b948-af793bd6d3ec&WorkflowInstanceID=%7b6037873D-3799-4637-821F-AC2E4F150BCB%7d

Then after clicking the button it instead redirects to:

> https://Contoso.com/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List=3ae780d1-8117-4d17-b948-af793bd6d3ec

The task is recorded as completed but the fields that are filled in on the form are discarded. I am wondering if somewhere in the process the WorkflowInstanceID is set to null but am unable to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

When you're exporting and importing workflows you can only do this in the same site. If you need to copy (import) a workflow to another site the steps are a little different.

First, you create a blank workflow in the destination site using SharePoint Designer. Go back to the source workflow and copy its content. Paste the content into the destination site workflow, and save it with a descriptive name.

Delete the previous imported workflow, and try the new workflow in the new site.